# Rail 5 Page Caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, page-caching

I am looking to do page caching with Rails 5, but the gem (actionpack-page_caching) doesn't seem to be Rails 5 supported yet.

What alternatives do I have?

Cheers,
Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gem `actionpack-page_caching` has a different branch that can be used for rails 5 compatibility.

Please replace `gem 'actionpack-pack-page_caching'` with `gem 'actionpack-page_caching', git: 'https://github.com/kord-as/actionpack-page_caching', branch: 'rails5'` to install the compatible version.

For more details refer to this issue -> [Rails 5 Support #31](https://github.com/rails/actionpack-page_caching/issues/31)